# xpath issue in extracting data

Tags: python, regex

I have to write xpath for fetching published

```
<div class="lpadding20" style="font-weight: normal;">
<strong>Published: </strong>6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM.
This list includes 414 eligible players.
</div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you provide with the code snippet, input and the output you are expecting

Comment: @asaika Please provide actual code, not pseudocode, as it is hard to understand what you would like otherwise. You can edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use split() function to do your task

```
str = 'published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM'
str=str.split('=')
str=str[1].split('at')
print('published date =',str[0],'\npublished time =',str[1])
```

you will get the same result

Comment: @asaika https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' I get this eerror

Answer (score 0):

This simple expression might work here:

```
published\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*at\s*(.+)\s*
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNYFF5/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"published\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*at\s*(.+)\s*"

test_str = "published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM"

subst = "published date = \\1\\npublished time = \\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: It worked well,now i need to loop it

Comment: str = player.xpath('//div[@class="lpadding20"]/text()')
        #str = 'raw_pubished'
        for str in player:
            regex = r"published\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*at\s*(.+)\s*"

            #test_str = "published = 6/11/2019 at 8:02 AM"

            subst = "published date = \\1\\npublished time = \\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
            result = re.sub(regex,subst, 0, re.MULTILINE)

        if result:
            print (result)

Comment: return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I face this error,for every data in from xpath regex shuld apply